# Invalid connecting string when using IP adress, hostname seems not an option

Tags: sql-server, django, iis

Recently I transferred a Django project to a windows server with IIS. Locally on my development workstation everything runs fine.

Now on the IIS server, when I'm using manage.py to locally test the site, it trows upon starting the local server an error:

> "django.db.utils.OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', 'Invalid connection string attribute', None, 0, -2147467259), None)"

Initially I can get it to startup by switching from IP to hostname. If I then proceed to try and browse the site I come upon the following error: "When using DATABASE PORT, DATABASE HOST must be an IP address."

Due to this I'm unable to use both the host name or IP address.

I've tried different drivers, different ways of creating the connection dictionary. ('ip,port', only IP, only host name) Nothing works when initiating the test server, except for when I use the port and host name. But as said above it then later on runs into a problem with a port nr expecting an IP address and not a hostname.

On my dev workstation this db dictionary is working fine, the website runs and data can be accessed:

```
'default': {
        'NAME' : 'database_name',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'PORT': '1433',
         'OPTIONS': {
            'provider': 'SQLOLEDB', 
            'use_legacy_date_fields': 'True',
            }
    }
```

I assumed after having all modules installed as on my dev workstation the connection would succeed.

Comment: try to use provider:SQLNCLI11  and your HOST string needs to contain both computer name or address and an Instance ID Use: 'HOST': 'COMPUTER-NAME\\SQLEXPRESS' or 'HOST': '127.0.0.1\\SQLEXPRESS'

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! SQLNCLI11 is giving an error being not present or not installed. I looked into installing the native driver, but it seems not to be supported by Windows server 2016.

Now looking into using PYODBC as a workaround.